# Smartedit - UserGroup is unable to upload/replace/remove Media attribute of component without being part of admingroup

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, smartedit

**Hybris Version: 1811**

Hi,

I recently made a new **non-admin** UserGroup that is a member of employeegroup and cmsmanagergroup. I'm running into a problem where I'am unable to upload/replace/remove the Media related to a Component using smartedit.

[image: Screenshot of SmartEdit]

The new UserGroup has read/write permission to both Content Catalog Versions (Staged/Online) and has read/change/create/remove Type Permissions on the Multimedia types (Media, Media Folders, Media Containers, Media Formats, Media Contexts, Conversion Group) in Back Office.

The new UserGroup is able to edit everything else in the component except for the Media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding a Readable/Writable Language, in this case "English [en]", to the UserGroup.

[Back Office Readable/Writable Language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0FTR.png)

Cheers!